# Using stat_summary function in R to plot data by different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have data from animal experiments divided into three categories. First 1) KO and WT, 2) time point and 3) Ipsilateral or contralateral. I need to represent those three variables in a single graph. I am using the following ggplot command:

```
    Line_Iba1_Area <- ggplot(M_Iba1_Area, aes(x = Group, y = value, colour = variable, shape = Stamm, group=interaction(variable, Stamm))) + 

  theme_classic () + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Times", color="black", face="bold", size=16, hjust=0.5, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 20, l = 0)))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family = "Times", color="black", face="bold", size=16, margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b =0, l = 0))) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family = "Times", color="black", face="bold", size=16, angle=90)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_text(face="bold", family="Times", colour="black", size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(family = "Times", color = "black", size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(family = "Times", color = "black", size=12)) +
  labs(title = "Iba1 Area", x = "Time Point", y = "Labeled Area (pixels)", colour = "Hemisphere") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1. Control", "2. 1Day", "3. 3Days", "4. 7Days", "5. 14Days"),
                   labels=c("Naive","1 Day", "3 Days", "7 Days", "14 Days")) + 

  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size=2, aes(group = variable)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", size=0.7, aes(group = variable)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +  

  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()) +

  facet_grid(Stamm ~ .)
```

Then I get [image]

However, they are just to lines. An I need for 1) ipsilateral-KO, contraletral-KO, ipsilateral-WT, contraletral-WT

If I add at the end  facet_grid(Stamm ~ .) I obtain all the variables I need but divided in two axis (two graphs).

[image]

What I need is a combination of both (with the four specified lines). I would appreciate if you can provide me useful examples to achieve this.

Comment: Can you post your data? Otherwise, there isn't much for us to work with

Comment: @camille, thank you for the answer. I appreciate your support. Here is the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DzP7N4-mq8lCKZdt9wQF7Rz7W_FkPqMu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To be more specific, it's easiest if you post a representative sample of the data directly in the question, such as the output of `dput`

Comment: or even more specific, ideally do not dput your whole data frame, but only its head